# PyCrypto returns a keysize error for AES

Tags: python, hash, aes, pycrypto

I'm trying to write a program to encrypt files using AES, however I get a

> ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

error no matter the size of the key.

My code for generating the AES object is

```
def AESEncryptor(Seed, Block = 16): #Generate AES key and Cipher
    iv = Random.new().read(Block)
    cipher = AES.new(Seed.encode('utf8'), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return cipher, iv
```

And my code for generating the key is

```
def genNewSeed(k=2048): #Generate seed for new AES key
    return hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(32)).hexdigest()[:11]
```

Which, according to `sys.getsizeof()` is equal to 32 bits yet it still returns the error

Comment: read carefully. you say it's 32 bit but needs to be 16, 32 bytes

Comment: I feel extremely stupid now, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're slicing off only 11 bytes from a hex-encoded "seed" of 64 characters. Keep in mind that keys are supposed to have high entropy, otherwise it's easier to brute force them.

I suggest you use:

```
def AESEncryptor(Seed, Block = 16): #Generate AES key and Cipher
    iv = Random.new().read(Block)
    cipher = AES.new(Seed, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return cipher, iv

def genNewSeed(k=2048): #Generate seed for new AES key
    return hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(32)).digest()
```

This will give you a 32 byte key which makes this AES-256. If you want AES-128, then you can slice the last 16 bytes off:

```
hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(32)).digest()[:16]
```

You cannot use `sys.getsizeof()` to determine the size of a key, because it includes all kinds of internal counters and data. For example, an empty string has already a size of 21 bytes. That's why you would thought that you got 32 byte when you only got 11 (21 + 11 = 32). Use the built-in `len(key)` instead.

Comment: My only problem with this is the key needs to be encrypted with RSA afterwards and `digest()` returns values that we can't seemingly encrypt with RSA and using `hexdigest()` produces a value greater then 32. Is using `md5(Seed).hexdigest()` going to produce a high enough entropy or will I need to rethink this?

Comment: (1) I don't know your code, but RSA with a key size of at least 344 bit (`(32+11)*8`) can encrypt 32 bytes of data if PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is used. Though, you should never use RSA keys smaller than 2048 bit nowadays (3072 bit is better), so there should be enough space to put the AES key there. (2) You cannot use `hexdigest()` on the output of SHA-256, because you will get 64 chars/bytes which would result in a 512 bit key which is not supported by AES.

Comment: (1) My code for encrypting the seed is `return r.encrypt(str(seed).encode('utf8'), crt)` where crt is the public key. I'm unsure of what you mean by PKCS#1 v1.5 padding as I'm relatively new to this. When I use your code I get the error `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)` (2) Do you recommend we use a RSA key larger then 2048 bits, and what size do you recommend for a good balance of security and performance?

Comment: (1) The key is already a byte string. You don't need to convert it to a string and then encode it again. Try `r.encrypt(seed, crt)` (2) It depends how much you want to secure the data. 2048 seems fine for now and the next couple of years. You should benchmark what kind of performance penalty you can live with on your system.

Comment: (1) Working now, thank you for that, should increase the security a good bit (2) Ok, since the client for this is not exactly a high profile target we should be good to use a key of 2048 for now and bump the keysize up in a few years. Thank you